# Unable to see all the leads in my database for CRM Module

Tags: crm, odoo-8

I have given the full access of the user for the see all leads in Odoo 8.0 but I have not found leads/Opportunity in my local database but when I will check with fresh database then its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're filtering all the other Leads
Check that no filter is active in your search box

Comment: this question seems like a comment more than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Its problem for rules setting in group for users. In group setting set the rules page all need access of users.
Like you can search leads and select all fields related to leads